# Terraform required_version refers to .terrafrom-version

Tags: terraform

My Apologies if this is a repeat question. I have a terraform repo list this:

project/

├── .terraform-version

└── my-terraform-config/

```
└── main.tf
```

I would like to configurate "required_version" by referring the version to the file ".terrafrom-version" rather than hardcoding. This is helpful to automate upgrade process in some cases

Tried templatefile() and external data, but they are not allowed. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: This would not be supported because it is best in TF to define requirements and dependencies within the config. This is because TF also directly manages these similar to e.g. go, puppet, ansible etc., as opposed to other languages where other tools e.g. cargo, pip, gem, npm, etc. manage these.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible with vanilla terraform but you could solve this with terragrunt.

Use the [attribute](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#terraform_version_constraint) `terraform_version_constraint` in a file at the root of your repository (root.hcl per ex) to set the version and use the include function in every layer to include the root.hcl file.

```
include "root" {
  path           = find_in_parent_folders("root.hcl")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two locations have slightly different meanings:

- The `required_version` argument specifies *for a single module* which versions of Terraform it's known to be compatible with.

  It's valid and expected for different modules in the same configuration to have different requirements, as long as they can all agree on at least one version they are all compatible with.
- The `.terraform-version` file (which is actually a third-party convention, rather than part of Terraform itself) tells a version manager tool how to select a single Terraform version to use for the entire configuration.

  This selection should typically be far more specific than what you'd specify in a `required_version` argument, because it specifies *which version to select*, which is a different question than "which set of versions would be valid to select from?"

If you have the intention of setting both of these to the same value then that suggests that you only have one of the above needs, and so you should just leave the other one unset. For example, if your primary concern is making sure that everyone working with this configuration selects the same version then you should make a `.terraform-version` file, but you can leave `required_version` totally unset.

The usual strategy for deciding what to put in `required_version` is to set it to `>=` whatever version of Terraform you initially tested the module with. If you later change the module in a way that requires a newer version of Terraform then you could update `required_version` at that point, but if all that's changed is that your team has agreed to use a newer version of Terraform to work with the configuration then updating `.terraform-version` is sufficient, and you can leave `required_version` unchanged as long as the module is still compatible with previous versions of Terraform.